# Having multiple pages with multiple identical elements managed by a single code

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, element

in my xamarin application I have multiple pages that contain the same elements (header and horizontal menu), and every time I have to make a change I have to change the code in every single page, there is a way to insert fixed elements in each page ?

Comment: yes, create a custom base page that your pages inherit from

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In xamarin, use **Xamarin.Forms control templates** to achieve what you want.

First create a template, design the style you want and set bindable parameters. Then when you use it, you only need to import the class directly, and you can flexibly bind the values you want to use.

For more information, please refer to the official documentation: [Xamarin.Forms control templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/control-template).